# why form not submit in laravel 5.4

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-5.4

i have a form for User Registration, it was working perfect before but now its not submit and doesn't get any error. i tried to show all my post data but its not post any data.. please help

```html
 <form role="form" id="reg-form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('/create_user') }}">
                    {{  csrf_field() }}
                    <h2>Create Account</h2>
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-6" id="user-firstname">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="displayName" name="displayName" placeholder="Choose your display name" required="required">
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required="required">
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" onkeyup="checkPass(); return false;" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="required">
   <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
  </div>
</div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/create_user', 'Auth\RegisterController@createUser');
```

**Method**

```
public function createUser(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
 }
```

Comment: When it was working before, what have you changed?

Comment: I can't see any submit button. If you're submitting the form with JS, look into browser console, maybe there is an error.

Comment: Where's the code for thr submit button?

Comment: @pseudoanime  please check after edit ..

Comment: @StephenHendricks i haven't changed any thing

Comment: check your laravel error log

Comment: Have you checked your console on the browser? there seems to be a few javascript functions defined, maybe those are causing errors.

Comment: @StephenHendricks what is Laravel Error log? can u explain me i am new in laravel

Comment: @pseudoanime yes brother i check it  but didn't get any error

Comment: Have you checked the laravel error logs? navigate to the storage\logs folder. and check the latest log.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to close some open tag above the form. It happened to me too.

Answer (score 0):

Possible error is the `"/"`

```
<form role="form" id="reg-form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('/create_user') }}">
```

so plz remove it like

```
<form role="form" id="reg-form" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('create_user') }}"> {{-- '/' removed --}}
```

and also in

```
Route::post('create_user', 'Auth\RegisterController@createUser'); // '/' removed
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{{ csrf_field }}` with `{!! csrf_field !!}}`. It will work